# Windows Work flow assemblies not picking up

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense, workflow-foundation-4

We we trying to create a work flow dll using Windows Work Flow but we are running into major problems regarding referencing.

1.) We have a class that calls an activity but the class cannot pick up the activity that has already been created

`WorkflowAcivity workflowActivity = new WorkflowActivity(string id)`

This then throws an error message saying cannot find `WorkflowActivity`

2.) We then added extra assemblies, like one of our other dll's, Visual Studio also cant find these references when we call a class in those dll's we are referencing.

[image]

3.) Intellisence has also stopped working??

[image]

[image]

What do we do to fix this, is it the version we are using or are there any other assemblies we are missing here??

We have tried opeing the solution on another pc, uninstalled vs 2012 and installed vs 2013 and still have no luck!

Comment: I take it that the typo in the first line of code is just from writing an example.

WorkflowAcivity is missing the T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got caused by System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll  referencing some dll's that were missing and caused the workflow to break without any warnings.

Removing this dll or adding the referenced dlls back in (System.Runtime.dll and System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll) fixed the problem.

[Microsoft ticket for this.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809676/microsoft-net-http-in-a-workflow-project-destroys-intellisense)